# How to check if two device files are equal in C?

Tags: c, linux

I want to check if two device files are equal in C, without accessing the underlying devices.

Can this be done using stat and lstat?

Comment: `struct stat` has the device number under `.st_dev`. See the manpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if two device files are the same, call `stat` on each of them, and check that they're both the same type of device (block or character) and that their `.st_rdev` members are equal.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int arc, char **argv)
{
    struct stat s1, s2;
    char *err;

    if (stat(argv[1], &s1) < 0) {
        err = strerror(errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't stat %s: %s\n", argv[1], err);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (stat(argv[2], &s2) < 0) {
        err = strerror(errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't stat %s: %s\n", argv[2], err);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (S_ISCHR(s1.st_mode) && S_ISCHR(s2.st_mode) && s1.st_rdev == s2.st_rdev) {
        printf("Same char device\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (S_ISBLK(s1.st_mode) && S_ISBLK(s2.st_mode) && s1.st_rdev == s2.st_rdev) {
        printf("Same block device\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("devices do not match\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `stat` structure? You can find the size of a file, and many many things. `.st_dev` should works in your case.